# sql server reading xml doc

Tags: sql-server, xml

My request xml is in this format

```
  <Tr>
    <Row id="50000" type =A/> 
    <Row id="50002" type =B/> 
    <Row id="50003" type =C/>
    <Row id="50004" type =C/>
   </Tr>
```

Is there a way in SQL Server to parse this xml in a stored procedure and create a temp table to fill in records in this format

```
Type A - 50000
Type B - 50002
Type C - 50003,500004
```

OR this format

```
Type     id
A       50000
B       50002
C       50003
C       50004
```

- List item

Comment: Yes, there is. What have you tried already?

Comment: my idea was to use for xml to loop through the elemnts and insert in temp table.but i am having issue to query data with for xml

Answer (score 1):

Once you make your XML be a **valid** XML, then yes, you can easily parse it into rows and columns in T-SQL:

(*here, the `@input` variable is defined as `XML`  and set a fixed value - this could be the input parameter in your stored procedure*)

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<Tr>
    <Row id="50000" type="A" /> 
    <Row id="50002" type="B" /> 
    <Row id="50003" type="C" />
    <Row id="50004" type="C" />
   </Tr>'

SELECT
    Type = XCol.value('@type', 'varchar(10)'),
    ID = XCol.value('@id', 'int')
FROM 
    @input.nodes('Tr/Row') AS XTbl(XCol)
```

Gives you the desired output (the second style - one row per `<Row>` entry in your XML)